Space-for-time Derivative Substitution in Solving for Elliptical Orbit
I am currently working on a simulation of the Newton's Cannonball thought experiment, in which a stone is launched horizontally from atop a tall mountain at a high speed (in the absence of air) and either lands back on Earth or enters an elliptical orbit, returning to its starting point over and over.
I am curious about finding an analytical solution to the trajectory of such a stone. I am able to show that, in polar coordinates, the radial force on the stone
$F = m(\ddot{r}-r\dot{\phi}^2)$.
I was not sure how to proceed, so I found a paper, Central-Force Laws for an Elliptic Orbit. At the bottom of the first page of the paper, the next step taken is a "substitution of space- for time-derivatives", and yields the equation
$$F=4mf^2r^{-5}(rr''-2r'^2-r^2)$$
Where $f=r^2\dot \phi /2$ and $r=r(\phi)$, $r'=\frac{dr}{d\phi}$, and $r''=\frac{d^2r}{d\phi^2}$.
Would anyone please tell me what is meant by the substitution of space for time derivatives?

This is done by application of the chain rule;  basically, you have
$$
\dot{r} = \frac{dr}{dt} = \frac{d\phi}{dt} \frac{dr}{d\phi} = \dot{\phi} r' = \frac{2 f}{r^2} r'.
$$
Similar techniques allow you to write $\ddot{r}$ in terms of derivatives of $r$ with respect to $\phi$.
Getting it into the form given probably relies on using the fact that $f$ is a constant due to the conservation of angular momentum.  Also, note that  $$
f = r^2 \dot{\phi}/2 = \frac{1}{2} r^2 \frac{d\phi}{dt},
$$
and
$$
F = m (r \ddot{r} - r \dot{\phi}^2).
$$
It may be hard to tell from the scans, but the dots are (should be) there.
